# Why does the MessageKit (`JSQMessagesViewController` replacement) input field disappears when VC segues from-right?

Tags: swift, messagekit

I am trying to integrate `MessageKit` (`JSQMessagesViewController` replacement) into my project.

From my `didSelectRowAt` of messages table I segue to my `ConversationVC` which subclasses `MessagesViewController` (`MessageKit` requirement)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let conversationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationVC") as? ConversationVC else { return }
    self.presentDetail(conversationVC)

    }//end func
```

This segues perfectly fine using the following custom function to present a VC:

```
    func presentDetail(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController){
        //constant to hold animation
        let transition = CATransition()

        transition.duration =  0.20 //seconds
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }//end func
```

**The problem is that once `ConversationVC` is presented from-right, the input message field at the bottom disappears If I use a standard segue (modally) then it shows.**

[image]

Comment: Have you try to became the first responder `becomeFirstResponder()` in the `viewWillApprear`

Comment: No, as I decided to move away and decided to build my own messaging engine. I appreciate your input though :)