# App does not navigate to destination VC programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to navigate from `ConversationsListVC` (source) to `ConversationVC` (destination) programmatically by instantiating the source VC (`self`) as the root navigation controller VC and then instantiating the destination VC so that I can push navigate.

**I get the print statements onto the console (see below) but the app does not navigate to the destination VC, the app doesn't crash or throw any error. what am I missing here?**

```
debug 1
debug 2
```

function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("debug 1")

    var window: UIWindow!

    guard let convoVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationVC") as? ConversationVC else { return }

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(convoVC, animated: true)

    print("debug 2")


}//end func
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one maybe the window instance is not correctly.

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationVC") as! ConversationVC
        navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

and make sure your viewcontroller is assign with the Identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can't just randomly create a new `UINavigationController` and push the destination onto it. You need to push the destination VC onto the `UINavigationController` in which `self` is currently embedded in.

If `self` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` already, do:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(convoVC, animated: true)
```

If the source VC is not embedded in a `UINavigationController`, you need to do that in the storyboard.

Since you are using storyboards, you can also consider adding a push segue between the source and destination, and performing that segue:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "someIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: thanks @Sweeper, the source VC is currently not embedded in a navigation controller and i'm reluctant to as I have built UI elements which are embedded that make-up the navigation controls at the top of the VC. I have added a segue between the VCs from the storyboard but I would like to push the destination controller from right-left, is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @Roggie Sounds like you should write your own subclass of `UINavigationController` and `UINavigationBar`. Another alternative is to write your own custom segue.

Comment: funny you say that, check this earlier [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585623/why-does-the-messagekit-jsqmessagesviewcontroller-replacement-input-field-di)  I posted. The custom segue-from-right works perfectly but the default message input field at the bottom disappears.